# Define area of ​the video in which the mask will act

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I have a script that according to a mask detects some objects on the screen, however I have an area of ​​interest or I want to apply the mask only in a certain area of ​​the video, here is an example image:

[image]

And below is my script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#Python + Open CV - Detecção de Fogo - Script Desenvolvido por Matheus Arruda
#0 -> busca o video da webcam // "nome_do_arquivo.mp4" faz a detecção com base em um video
video = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = video.read()
    if not grabbed:
        break
    #filtro de exibição (blur)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
    #Metodo de detecção de cor (pode ser usado HSV ou RGB) RGB se utiliza o metodo padrão de cor, exemplo: Vermelho 255,0,0
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #Parametros de detecção de cor 
    minimo = [18, 70, 50]#[18, 50, 50]
    maximo = [35, 255, 255] #[35, 255, 255]
    minimo = np.array(minimo, dtype="uint8")
    maximo = np.array(maximo, dtype="uint8")
    #Na mascara, seto o tipo de filtro que nesse caso é o HSV e os ranges de detecção minimo e máximo
    mascara = cv2.inRange(hsv, minimo, maximo)
    #Desenho o contorno dos objetos detectados
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mascara, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for contour in contours:
        cv2.drawContours(frame, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)


    #Saida, frame = video, aplicado HSV e a mascara definida acima
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, hsv, mask=mascara)
    #Conta a quantidade de pixels que não estão com vermelho, com base nessa informação geramos a condição de detectação de fogo
    px_sem_vermelho = cv2.countNonZero(mascara)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    if int(px_sem_vermelho) > 1500: #Padrão de detecção (20.000)
        print ('Detectado Fogo')
        cv2.putText(frame,'Vazando Ferro Liquido',(10,330), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        print(px_sem_vermelho)
    elif int(px_sem_vermelho) > 900:
        print('Sem Fogo')
        cv2.putText(frame,'Vazando Pouco Ferro Liquido',(10,330), font, 0.7,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
        print(int(px_sem_vermelho))
    else:
        print('Sem Fogo')       
        print(int(px_sem_vermelho))

    cv2.imshow("Filtro Deteccao", cv2.resize(output,(640,480)))
    cv2.imshow("Video", cv2.resize(frame,(640,480)))
    #print("output:", frame)

        #print("output:".format(mascara))
        #Tecla 'q' definida para sair do programa
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: what is the difference between mask and area of interest in your task? Typically a mask IS already some area in an image

Comment: @Micka My mascara captures the entire frame of the video, example my video has an area of ​​640x480 and the mascara is applied throughout the area, however I need the mascara to apply only to a certain part of the image at the same time I need all the video to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the segmentation/detection part of the algorithm is not tied to specific image sizes. Therefore, what can you do is to use a Region of Interest to select the interesting part of the image, then you run the algorithm on this ROI and merge the results back (which can be done, since you know the location of the ROI).

In order to extract a ROI, you can use simple indexing:

```
roi = image[ystart:yend][xstart:xend]
```

Now, you can use `roi` as any image. You run the algorithm on it, and then you change the corresponding part in `image` using a simple assignment:

```
image[ystart:yend][xstart:xend] = processedROI
```